# pip error: An error occurred during configuration: option use-feature: invalid choice: '2020-resolver,fast-deps'

Tags: pip, replit

After any pip command is used, this error is shown:

```
An error occurred during configuration: option use-feature: invalid choice: '2020-resolver,fast-deps' (choose from '2020-resolver', 'fast-deps')
```

I have looked online and tried

```
pip config set --user global.use-feature 2020-resolver,fast-deps
```

but it says

```
Warning: --use-feature=2020-resolver no longer has any effect, since it is now the default dependency resolver in pip. 
This will become an error in pip 21.0. Writing to /home/runner/(repl name)/.config/pip/pip.conf
```

and doesn't fix the error above, as it still does gives the above error when typing any pip command. After that, I tried just writing

```
pip config set --user global.use-feature fast-deps
```

but it just returns the first error.
I have python3 installed and pip 22.1.
Any help to solve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This seems to be related https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8671 . Did you try to re-install pip?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're able to uninstall/reinstall pip on replit, and if there is a way I don't know how to. pip uninstall gives the same error.

Comment: I assume that this issue is only for one of your replit projects? Can you share your `pip.conf` of that project? It should be in the folder `<your_project>/.config/pip`.

Comment: Lmao bro used Replit to package a Pip module

Comment: I didn't understand. What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

just delete pip.conf
i also encountered this issue after reinstalling pip,
now its fixed

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue and it took me 3 days to try many ways.
Finally, I passed the issue after deleting 2 pip hidden-folders under the:

```
C:\User\<my win account>\AppData\Roaming\pip

C:\User\<my win account>\AppData\Local\pip
```

Then install pip again, Issue will be gone.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try doing whatever you're doing through the replit interface instead of the command line since sometimes it works